# GLSL Shader Editors for Linux

Tags: shaders, glsl, linux

Are there any good IDE's for linux that lets us edit GLSL shaders and visualize their effect?

Note : Shader Designer By Typhoon Labs is a good option but I am looking for alternatives as this software has some issues with Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [Shader Maker](http://cg.in.tu-clausthal.de/teaching/shader_maker/index.shtml) or [Lumina](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lumina/files/).

Answer (score 2):

Try using QtCreator, the latest version has GLSL shader support, code completition and syntax highlighting.

Comment: +1. It's actually some of the best built-in shader support I've seen for an IDE.